# how to add events in calender through jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, calendar

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //start of calender
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({

      time: '2016-02',
      events: {
        "2016-03-30": {"number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider"},
        "2016-03-30": {"number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider"},
        "2016-03-26": {"number": 1, "url": "http://w3widgets.com"}, 
        "2016-04-03":{"number": 1}, 
        "2016-05-12": {}
      }
    });//end of calender
```

Events which are mentioned above are static and given in an example which i found in the web. Those events are visible in the calender. However, I want to generate events dynamically from my database. I have tried to produce a string format from php in the form of "events:{...}". I have that string in a variable. However, when i place that variable in 'responsive-calender' function, the variable is printing inside the webpage as variable name. Not able to print the string inside that variable.
    I just want to make events dynamic. How to do that?

Comment: Please provide link or information what plugin do you use, I mean this responsiveCalendar

Comment: http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not php guy, but I believe here the idea is more important. So basically the idea would be that you can pass from server the

```
Dictionary<DateTime, CalendarEvent>
```

So the key would be the date and CalendarEvent will be an object with properties like number, badgeClass, url etc.

This server-side dictionary should be serialized to javascript object which you expect so it will be something like that:

```
var serverEvents = 
{
    "2013-04-30": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://sth.com",
    "2013-04-26": {number": 2, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://sth.com2"
}
```

After that you create your calendar like:

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
  time: '2016-02',
  events: serverEvents
});
```

So basically here the most important part is passing data from server and serialization. In C# it would be

```
Dictionary<DateTime, CalendarEvent>
```

and it will be easily serialized to the object you want. I guess in PHP there is similar soultion.